# Got syntax error when I tried to create a table in a database

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to create a table in R Studio (on a local MySQL server)
The code is:

```
create table conditions(
    condition varchar(255),
    explanation varchar(255),
    cid INT not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (cid)
);
```

And after running it I got

Show in New Window
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition varchar(255),
explanation varchar(255),
cid INT not null,
' at line 2
Failed to execute SQL chunk

What could be the reason for this? I am confused since I could create other tables using the same way

I created other tables using the same syntax and those tables could be established

Answer (score 0):

The word "condition" is a reserved word in MySQL, and you cannot use it as a table name or column name without enclosing it in backticks (`).
Try changing the script to this:

```
   create table conditions(
        `condition` varchar(255),
        explanation varchar(255),
        cid INT not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (cid)
   );
```